# Can we send requests directly on a bare metal machine in OpenStack?

Tags: networking, openstack, network-interface, openstack-neutron

Do I need Controllers and Neutron nodes to send requests on a bare metal machine in OpenStack? Can we send requests directly on a bare metal machine without passing them through controller/neutron nodes?

Comment: What do you mean by "sending requests"?  Can you describe exactly what it is you want to do?

Comment: When we want to send request to a Nova virtual machine we must assign floating IP to this VM. When we sending a request to a nove VM our request goes from one machine through Neutron node to Nova VM and then back. My question is: If we don't use Nova VM's but bare metal nodes (which is Ironic) can we send request directly from Machine A to Machine B and don't use a Neutron node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Provider networking](http://docs.openstack.org/liberty/networking-guide/scenario-provider-ovs.html) allows you to attach Nova instances directly to existing layer 2 networks so that they do not need to transit the Neutron controller for either local or external network access.  You can mix-and-match provider networks with normal OpenStack virtual networks depending on your needs and available network resources.

This same solution would allow baremetal machines to communicate without involving the Neutron host.

Comment: Thank you very much for help!)